# In what version of jquery the autocomplete feature is introduced?

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery 1.2.6 for the whole site but I am having difficulties in implementing jquery . Can anyone tell me in what version of jquery the autocomplete feature is brought and is there any process to upgrade the jquery of a older version to a newer version. For ex: upgrading from 1.2.6 ro 1.8. Is there any process to be followed.

Comment: The upgrade process involves reading the release notes for each intermediate version very carefully, fixing any issues, and testing that things work afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autocomplete is a part of [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) and is not included out of the box in the jQuery framework.

Autocomplete was introduced in jQuery UI 1.8, which is not to be confused with jQuery 1.8, but was released around the time of jQuery 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete isn't found in jQuery but [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)